# Add links on right of footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I have these 3 links on the left side of footer, on the left side of the logo. I would like to add another 3 that are on the right side of the logo. But kinda float right and will always be 100px or so from the right side of web browser.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2f1mcoy/):

For the css I tried basically copying and pasting the list and getting it to float right but couldn't get it working right.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #30659B;
  height: 135px;
  width: 100%
}

.logo2 {
  width: 150px;
  fill: white;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 27px;
}

.nav2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 0;
}

.li2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.li2 a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  /*   margin: 32px 20px 0px 20px; */
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="logo2">
    <svg class="logo2" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 268 50"><title>Artboard 1</title><path         d="M46.26,10.5h6.46V35.17H65.55v5.69H46.26Z"/><path  d="M82.8,38.59a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-7,2.82c-3.5,0-7.65-2.37-7.65-7.28,0-5.14,4.14-7,7.65-7,2.91,0,5.51.91,7,2.69v-3c0-2.23-1.91-3.69-4.82-3.69a9.25,9.25,0,0,0-6.42,2.59l-2.18-3.87A14.42,14.42,0,0,1,79,18.33c5,0,9.6,2,9.6,8.33v14.2H82.8Zm0-5.74a5.78,5.78,0,0,0-4.64-1.91c-2.28,0-4.14,1.23-4.14,3.32s1.87,3.23,4.14,3.23a5.78,5.78,0,0,0,4.64-1.91Z"/><path d="M109.15,38.08a10.29,10.29,0,0,1-7.74,3.32c-4.82,0-7.1-2.64-7.1-6.92V18.88h5.78V32.21c0,3,1.59,4.05,4.05,4.05a6.47,6.47,0,0,0,5-2.5V18.88h5.78v22h-5.78Z"/><path d="M135.5,27.57c0-3-1.59-4.1-4.05-4.1a6.26,6.26,0,0,0-5,2.59V40.86h-5.78v-22h5.78v2.87a10.07,10.07,0,0,1,7.69-3.41c4.82,0,7.15,2.73,7.15,7V40.86H135.5Z"/><path d="M157.26,18.33c4.51,0,7.24,2,8.69,4l-3.78,3.5a5.44,5.44,0,0,0-4.64-2.37c-3.5,0-6,2.55-6,6.37s2.46,6.42,6,6.42a5.55,5.55,0,0,0,4.64-2.37L166,37.4c-1.46,2-4.19,4-8.69,4-6.78,0-11.65-4.78-11.65-11.56S150.48,18.33,157.26,18.33Z"/><path d="M184.61,27.48c0-3-1.59-4-4.1-4a6.4,6.4,0,0,0-5,2.59V40.86h-5.78V10.5h5.78V21.74a10.17,10.17,0,0,1,7.74-3.41c4.82,0,7.15,2.64,7.15,6.92V40.86h-5.78Z"/><path d="M196.12,49.24V18.88h5.78v2.78a8.49,8.49,0,0,1,6.78-3.32c5.64,0,9.74,4.19,9.74,11.52s-4.1,11.56-9.74,11.56A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,201.9,38v11.2Zm10.74-25.76a6.47,6.47,0,0,0-5,2.5v7.78a6.62,6.62,0,0,0,5,2.5c3.32,0,5.55-2.59,5.55-6.42S210.19,23.47,206.86,23.47Z"/><path d="M235.94,38.59a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-7,2.82c-3.51,0-7.65-2.37-7.65-7.28,0-5.14,4.14-7,7.65-7,2.91,0,5.51.91,7,2.69v-3c0-2.23-1.91-3.69-4.82-3.69a9.25,9.25,0,0,0-6.42,2.59l-2.18-3.87a14.42,14.42,0,0,1,9.6-3.46c5,0,9.6,2,9.6,8.33v14.2h-5.78Zm0-5.74a5.78,5.78,0,0,0-4.64-1.91c-2.28,0-4.14,1.23-4.14,3.32s1.87,3.23,4.14,3.23a5.78,5.78,0,0,0,4.64-1.91Z"/><path d="M262.57,38.08a8.62,8.62,0,0,1-6.78,3.32c-5.55,0-9.74-4.19-9.74-11.51s4.14-11.56,9.74-11.56a8.47,8.47,0,0,1,6.78,3.37V10.5h5.83V40.86h-5.83Zm0-12.11a6.36,6.36,0,0,0-5-2.5c-3.28,0-5.55,2.59-5.55,6.42s2.28,6.37,5.55,6.37a6.36,6.36,0,0,0,5-2.5Z"/><path d="M7.56,38.52l8.13,10.73a1.41,1.41,0,0,0,2.16,0L26,38.52a1.34,1.34,0,0,0-.56-2L18.53,33A4,4,0,0,0,15,33l-6.89,3.5A1.34,1.34,0,0,0,7.56,38.52Z"/><path d="M30.31,14.15,18.12.82a1.91,1.91,0,0,0-2.7,0L3.23,14.15a4,4,0,0,0-1,2.16L-.38,34.52c-.13.9,1,1.53,1.93,1.07L4.29,34.2l12.48-6.37L29.25,34.2,32,35.59c.92.47,2.06-.17,1.93-1.07l-2.57-18.2A4,4,0,0,0,30.31,14.15Z"/></svg>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav2">
    <li class="li2"><a href="/aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/ourwork">OUR WORK</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/services">SERVICES</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--
    <div id="sup">
     <ul class="nav3">
  <li class="li3"><a href="/aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li class="li3"><a href="/ourwork">OUR WORK</a></li>
  <li class="li3"><a href="/services">SERVICES</a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
-->

</footer>
```

Here is what the footer should look like in the end
[image: img]

Comment: Why not just center align all your links within the entire width of the footer and just put them in there.  That why no matter how the page changes you are set to go?

Comment: Why not add the logo to the list and add a class with margin/padding?

Comment: Check my solution if it helps :) Made use of flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve that footer with the use of flexbox as demonstrated below. Hope, this helps.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #30659B;
  width: 100vw;
}

.logo2 {
  width: 150px;
  fill: white;
  display: block;
}

.nav {
  padding:0;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  display: flex;  /*Generates a flexbox layout with default flex direction as row */
  width: 100%; /* Not really required */
  height:100px;
  align-items: center; /*Aligns contents vertically */
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  padding:0;
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  margin:5px;
}
li:first-child{
margin-left:100px;
}
li:last-child{
margin-right:100px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="li2"><a href="/aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/ourwork">OUR WORK</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/services">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li>
  <div class="logo2">
    <svg class="logo2" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 268 50"><title>Artboard 1</title><path         d="M46.26,10.5h6.46V35.17H65.55v5.69H46.26Z"/><path  d="M82.8,38.59a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-7,2.82c-3.5,0-7.65-2.37-7.65-7.28,0-5.14,4.14-7,7.65-7,2.91,0,5.51.91,7,2.69v-3c0-2.23-1.91-3.69-4.82-3.69a9.25,9.25,0,0,0-6.42,2.59l-2.18-3.87A14.42,14.42,0,0,1,79,18.33c5,0,9.6,2,9.6,8.33v14.2H82.8Zm0-5.74a5.78,5.78,0,0,0-4.64-1.91c-2.28,0-4.14,1.23-4.14,3.32s1.87,3.23,4.14,3.23a5.78,5.78,0,0,0,4.64-1.91Z"/><path d="M109.15,38.08a10.29,10.29,0,0,1-7.74,3.32c-4.82,0-7.1-2.64-7.1-6.92V18.88h5.78V32.21c0,3,1.59,4.05,4.05,4.05a6.47,6.47,0,0,0,5-2.5V18.88h5.78v22h-5.78Z"/><path d="M135.5,27.57c0-3-1.59-4.1-4.05-4.1a6.26,6.26,0,0,0-5,2.59V40.86h-5.78v-22h5.78v2.87a10.07,10.07,0,0,1,7.69-3.41c4.82,0,7.15,2.73,7.15,7V40.86H135.5Z"/><path d="M157.26,18.33c4.51,0,7.24,2,8.69,4l-3.78,3.5a5.44,5.44,0,0,0-4.64-2.37c-3.5,0-6,2.55-6,6.37s2.46,6.42,6,6.42a5.55,5.55,0,0,0,4.64-2.37L166,37.4c-1.46,2-4.19,4-8.69,4-6.78,0-11.65-4.78-11.65-11.56S150.48,18.33,157.26,18.33Z"/><path d="M184.61,27.48c0-3-1.59-4-4.1-4a6.4,6.4,0,0,0-5,2.59V40.86h-5.78V10.5h5.78V21.74a10.17,10.17,0,0,1,7.74-3.41c4.82,0,7.15,2.64,7.15,6.92V40.86h-5.78Z"/><path d="M196.12,49.24V18.88h5.78v2.78a8.49,8.49,0,0,1,6.78-3.32c5.64,0,9.74,4.19,9.74,11.52s-4.1,11.56-9.74,11.56A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,201.9,38v11.2Zm10.74-25.76a6.47,6.47,0,0,0-5,2.5v7.78a6.62,6.62,0,0,0,5,2.5c3.32,0,5.55-2.59,5.55-6.42S210.19,23.47,206.86,23.47Z"/><path d="M235.94,38.59a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-7,2.82c-3.51,0-7.65-2.37-7.65-7.28,0-5.14,4.14-7,7.65-7,2.91,0,5.51.91,7,2.69v-3c0-2.23-1.91-3.69-4.82-3.69a9.25,9.25,0,0,0-6.42,2.59l-2.18-3.87a14.42,14.42,0,0,1,9.6-3.46c5,0,9.6,2,9.6,8.33v14.2h-5.78Zm0-5.74a5.78,5.78,0,0,0-4.64-1.91c-2.28,0-4.14,1.23-4.14,3.32s1.87,3.23,4.14,3.23a5.78,5.78,0,0,0,4.64-1.91Z"/><path d="M262.57,38.08a8.62,8.62,0,0,1-6.78,3.32c-5.55,0-9.74-4.19-9.74-11.51s4.14-11.56,9.74-11.56a8.47,8.47,0,0,1,6.78,3.37V10.5h5.83V40.86h-5.83Zm0-12.11a6.36,6.36,0,0,0-5-2.5c-3.28,0-5.55,2.59-5.55,6.42s2.28,6.37,5.55,6.37a6.36,6.36,0,0,0,5-2.5Z"/><path d="M7.56,38.52l8.13,10.73a1.41,1.41,0,0,0,2.16,0L26,38.52a1.34,1.34,0,0,0-.56-2L18.53,33A4,4,0,0,0,15,33l-6.89,3.5A1.34,1.34,0,0,0,7.56,38.52Z"/><path d="M30.31,14.15,18.12.82a1.91,1.91,0,0,0-2.7,0L3.23,14.15a4,4,0,0,0-1,2.16L-.38,34.52c-.13.9,1,1.53,1.93,1.07L4.29,34.2l12.48-6.37L29.25,34.2,32,35.59c.92.47,2.06-.17,1.93-1.07l-2.57-18.2A4,4,0,0,0,30.31,14.15Z"/></svg>
  </div></li>
  <li class="li3"><a href="/aboutus">TWITTER</a></li>
  <li class="li3"><a href="/ourwork">FACEBOOK</a></li>
  <li class="li3"><a href="/services">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
 </ul>

</footer>
```

Comment: I really like this. I added your code but it sits at the top of the site. for some reason. no footer at all. I also changed the .nav to .nav2 to not interfere with the other nav i have for the header.

Comment: never mind! i must of done something wrong. It seems to be working now. Need to tweak a few things to get it just right. If i have any questions i will comment.

Comment: @WarrenBreedlove Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try with this



  <ul class="nav2">
    <li class="li2"><a href="/aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/ourwork">OUR WORK</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/services">SERVICES</a></li>
   <li class="li2"><svg class="logo2" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">Tu logo</svg></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/aboutus">TWITTER</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/ourwork">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/services">FACEBOOK</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I like this fix. i added it and removed the old css. But it wants to sit below the blue of the footer. any idea what i can add to the css to get it above the blue and always centered?

Comment: that's weird, your list are inside of <footer> tag?, there must be another style that is modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try with this css class:

```
.nav2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: That did not work. Ill keep messing with it as well but still sits below. This is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/h54qn